# send email to localhost from localhost via python

Tags: python, web-services, email, sendmail, smtplib

I'm building and testing a web service on my local machine before i put it in production. I want to test the mail service. I'm using the standard python email and smtplib libraries.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
fp = open('textfile', 'rb')
msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

me = 'me_email@localhost'
you = 'me_again_email@localhost'
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' %fp
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I have not configured sendmail and hence it throws an error. But since I just want to test my web service I am not concerned if sendmail cant send an email right now.  My service is designed to pulls some records off db and send them an email. So i want to know if this connection, python taking inputs from db and pushing an email is working. I want to receive the email on localhost sent via the script.

Answer (score 2):

An [SMTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) needs to be configured for sending emails. Sending emails is not possible unless you configure an SMTP server. More information on using python `smtplib` can be found in [pymotw.com](http://pymotw.com/2/smtplib/), [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm) and [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html).