# How to test email notifications of trac in local host ? Especially Mail2Trac plugin and Email2Trac plugin

Tags: email, smtp, ubuntu-14.04, trac, smtp-auth

I'm able to configure SMTP server so that whenever a ticket is created in Trac, the ticket will be sent to the gmail id.

Now the Email to Trac plugin and Mail 2 Trac Plugin works in such a way that, the emails received from the trac system will be replied back and the reply of that mail will be posted automatically as the comment in the ticket.

How to test this plugin functionality in localhost ? I donot know how to setup SMTP server so that I can receive emails generated by trac system inside my machine and I dont have idea how the reverse case (reply to the email) will work locally in my machine.

I'm working in Ubuntu 14.0.4

Guide me on how to do this.

Comment: Please, tell the correct plugin names. I have no idea which ones you mean.

Comment: I want to use the plugin mail2trac  in trac. I installed trac in my local system. But I don't know how to install this plugin and test it in my localhost before shipping it to the production. How I will test the mail2trac plugin locally ?

Comment: Have you read http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/MailToTracPlugin#Description and simply set "smtp_replyto" in your trac.ini?

Comment: Thanks for the info falkb . Thanks for the information. But to which smtp server I should set the variable "smtp_replyto" when I'm testing it locally ? How do I create a email server locally to test it ? If i'm setting it to my gmail id then I can see email coming to my gmail id whenever I create a ticket in the trac system (again trac installed locally and accessed via localhost) but to test this mail2trac plugin I need to reply back to the email I received.. How I will reply back unless I have local SMTP server ? Please guide if my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think smtp_replyto is simply set to an email address, e.g. root@localhost. That's all for the Trac part. Then install an SMTP server on your local machine. Refer to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951109/send-email-to-localhost-from-localhost-via-python) for how to do configure the SMTP server.

Comment: Falkb : Thanks for the info.. I will look into it.  Have you worked on this mail2trac plugin before ? Can you give more inputs on installing the plugin.. ?  [And your email id to contact].

Comment: Sorry, I don't use that plugin. I just read it out of my interest.

Comment: Thx falkb. Have you used email2trac plugin ? Or is there any guidelines to understand how to install and test plugins if trac ?